# Cleverbot Error: Bad Call to the API

Tags: javascript

I've setup cleverbot, and I have 89 correct sessions, but now I get this error:  "Error: Bad Call to the API"  Why it is happen? The code is correct.

POST:

```
user: ExampleUser
key:ExAmPlEkEy
nick:sess1485175086
text:test
```

RESULT:

```
Request URL:https://cleverbot.io/1.0/ask
Request Method:POST
Status Code:400 
Remote Address:104.24.113.140:443
```

Comment: Is this a reproduceable error? Also, I don't know anything about this service but is it wise to share your user/key?

Comment: Maybe cleverbot server is down, because I see same error on cleverbot.io site https://yadi.sk/i/M2cWQyX73ATCfV

Comment: @LiamMacDonald **newer** share username and password on internet. **NEVER**

Answer (score 0):

The cleverbot.io server was down. Now is ok.